# CSS: how to make a circle with 60% one color and 40% other color around an image?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a circle with 60% one color and 40% other color around an image.

I have tried using the below code,

```
//CSS
.waitlist .img-thumbnail {
    border: 2px solid #dee2e6;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #2A89F6 50%, transparent 50%),
                linear-gradient(-90deg, #CCC 50%, transparent 50%);
}

//HTML
<img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle img-thumbnail mb-2" width="100">
```

The output for above code is,

[image: Output for above code]

But I want the output as,

[image: Required Output]

Is it possible to achieve the required output?

Comment: I'd use SVG....at least until conical gradients are supported.

Comment: Hope this could help: [CSS Percentage Circle](http://circle.firchow.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```css
.box {
  border-radius:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(-40deg, grey 50%,transparent 0), /*adjust the deg value here to control the %*/
   linear-gradient(to right, red 50%,transparent 0),
   grey;
}
.box img {
  border-radius:50%;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=1069" >
</div>
```